# javascript Regular expression to search single word from quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegExp which matches a exact single word in quotes.

For Example:

- Edit the Expression Text to see matches Roll over "**matches**" or
  the expression for details.
- Edit the Expression Text to see matches Roll over '**matches** or the
  expression' for details.
- Edit the Expression's  Text to see matches Roll 'over **matches** or'
  the expression for details.

Characters in example string with bold font face should be selected.

One which we have made is :

```
"\s*((?:\w(?!\s+")+|\s(?!\s*"))+\w)\s*"|'\s*((?:\w(?!\s+')+|\s(?!\s*'))+\w)\s*'
```

but the problem is that it selects all the words which came between `' '` or `" "`. Any help please?

Comment: What if inside the quotes, you have something like `don't` or `14"`? Checking the odd/even number of quotes with a look-ahead won't help. I wonder if there is any safe regex solution for this task.

Comment: As it was already put in the comment, for such a task words containing apostrophes won't work. In case your texts don't have such words anyway it's unclear how you decided that in the third example exactly the second word should be a match. If you are interested in the first word in quotes or the last one, it would make sense. Could you give more details on what you need to match?